# Can't set up mail with VBA when changed to Windows 10

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

For long time I have used a macro to send an Excel worksheet via mail but when I updated to Windows 10 everything failed and I cannot understand why. This is the code:

```
TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
TempFileName = Range("B2") & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With Destwb
    .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, _
            FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    On Error Resume Next
   ' Change the mail address and subject in the macro before
   ' running the procedure.
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rngTo = .Range("B1")
        Set rngCc = .Range("B3")
        Set rngSubject = .Range("B2")
        Set rngBody = .Range("B2")
    End With

    With OutMail
        .To = rngTo
        .CC = rngCc
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = rngSubject
        .Body = "Adjunto para tu revisión y comentarios"
        .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
        ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following statement.
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
        ' display the mail.
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
End With

' Delete the file after sending.
Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
```

The problem is in the `.to, .cc, .subject` part.

If I debug the code I can see that the variables are filled, for example:

[image: The .toMail]

But when it sends or displays the fields they are empty. Also, if  manually fill the `.to="a@a.com"` it works.

Do you know what can it be?

Answer (score 0):

To/CC/BCC properties are recipient names. These properties are updated when the item is saved. Are you seeing empty To/CC in the Sent Items folder in Outlook?

You can also use `OutMail.Recpients.Add` for each recipient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for "To":

```
Set _To = OutMail.Recipient.Add(Range("A1"))
_To.Type = olTo
```

You can use for "CC":

```
Set _To = OutMail.Recipient.Add(Range("A2"))
_To.Type = olCC
```

My problem now is how to fix the other propieties, Subject and SentOnBehalfOnName

Answer (score -1):

Tomas

I just went to Windows 10 from 7. For some reason you have to add .Value.

Example 1.

```
With ActiveSheet
    Set rngTo = .Range("B1").Value
    Set rngCc = .Range("B3").Value
    Set rngSubject = .Range("B2").Value
    Set rngBody = .Range("B2").Value
End With
With OutMail
    .To = rngTo
    .CC = rngCc
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = rngSubject
End With
```

I wrote mine a little different. See example 2.

Example 2

```
 With OutMail
        .To = Range("AA22").Value
        .CC = Range("AB22").Value
        .Subject = Range("AA21").Value
End With
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O.,
`Set rngTo = .Range("B1").Value` is a type mismatch.